# Expectation from conditional distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and that thet conditional distribution of $X$ given that $Y=y$ is uniform on $(0,y)$ Find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$

My attempt : We have $Y \sim$ Unif$(0,1) $ and $f_{X|Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{y}$

Thus  $$E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$$
$$= E(\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x,y) dx) $$
$$= E(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{y}dx)$$

I am sure I am making mistake here. Can you help ?

Comment: This problem is number 38 from Chapter 3 in the third edition in Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross. I hope this helps others find this question faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written your conditional density incorrectly. It should be $f_{X\mid Y}(x,y) = \frac1y \mathbb 1_{[0,y]}$, i.e. it is $\frac1y$ on $[0,y]$ and $0$ outside. Then,

$$\begin{align}
E[X] &= E[E[X\mid Y]]\\
&=E\left[\int_0^\infty xf_{X\mid Y}(x,y) dx\right]\\
&=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^y \frac{x}{y} dx\right]dy\\
&=\int_0^1\frac y2dy\\
&=\frac14
\end{align}
$$

You can find the variance similarly.